# Sketch of Chutes and Ladders game

Tags: c++, c++11, community-challenge, sfml

The classic *Chutes and Ladders* game has a grid of 100 squares with various "chutes" (which send a player backwards) and "ladders" (which promote a player forward).  The goal here was to randomly create a series of these chutes and ladders such that the *net* effect is that there are 50 more squares that may be lost than gained.  I had considered finishing this off to a complete and playable game, but it doesn't seem to be a sufficiently interesting game to warrant the small additional effort.

Here's a screenshot of the result:

[image: Chutes and Ladders screenshot[1]]

### distrib.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include "distrib.h"

int makeDeltaValues(std::vector<int> &chutes, std::vector<int> &ladders, int target) 
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::weibull_distribution<> d{2.0, 20};
    auto badvalue = [](int a){ return (a<2) || (a>boxcount*2/3);};
    auto next{[&](){ int m; do { m=d(gen)+2; } while(badvalue(m)); return m;}};
    int iterations = 0;
    do {
        ++iterations;
        std::generate(ladders.begin(), ladders.end(), next);
        std::generate(chutes.begin(), chutes.end(), next);
        int lsum = std::accumulate(ladders.begin(), ladders.end(), 0);
        int csum = std::accumulate(chutes.begin(), chutes.end(), 0);
        // lsum must always be smaller or equal
        if (lsum > csum) {
            std::swap(csum, lsum);
            std::swap(chutes, ladders);
        }
        int delta = target - csum+lsum;
        // need to add delta distributed over chutes
        for (auto &v : chutes) {
            if (!badvalue(v+delta)) {
                v += delta;
                delta = 0;
            }
        }
        // force remainder into first element (usually zero)
        chutes.front() += delta;
    } while (badvalue(chutes.front()));
    return iterations;
}

std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> createLinks() 
{
    std::vector<int> ladders(9);
    std::vector<int> chutes(9);
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> links;
    links.reserve(ladders.size() + chutes.size());

    makeDeltaValues(chutes, ladders);
    for (auto item : ladders) {
        links.emplace_back(std::pair<int, int>{0, item});
    }
    for (auto item : chutes) {
        links.emplace_back(std::pair<int, int>{0, -item});
    }
    /* We now have the lengths of the various links, but
     * still need to translate those into starting and 
     * ending locations.  
     *
     * The method here is simple: we choose a random location
     * for the start and make sure that both start and end 
     * are clear.  If they aren't we keep guessing random
     * locations until we find a clear pair.  This is guaranteed
     * to work eventually.
     */

    std::mt19937 gen(std::random_device{}());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> d{2, boxcount-1};
    std::array<bool, boxcount> used;
    int start;
    int end;
    for (auto &p : links) {
        do {
            start = d(gen);
            end = p.second + start;
        } while (end > boxcount-1 || end < 2 || used[start] || used[end]);
        p.first = start;
        p.second = end;
        used[start] = used[end] = true;
    }
    return links;
}
```

### distrib.h

```
#ifndef DISTRIB_H
#define DISTRIB_H
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

constexpr int boxcount{100};

/*
 * populate the chutes and ladders vectors (which should already have nonzero size)
 * with random values such that sum(chutes)-sum(ladders) == target.
 */
int makeDeltaValues(std::vector<int> &chutes, std::vector<int> &ladders, int target=50);

/*
 * Creates a vector of start/end pairs within the range (1, boxcount-1] using
 * the makeDeltaValues() call above.  Note that for a boxcount of 100, 
 * starting or ending values of 1 or of 100 are not allowed, but all values
 * between those are allowed.
 */
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> createLinks();

#endif // DISTRIB_H
```

### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <cmath>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "distrib.h"

# define M_PIl          3.141592653589793238462643383279502884L /* pi */

/*
 * A connector is an arrow shape that is drawn from point a to point b.
 */
class Connector : public sf::Drawable, public sf::Transformable {
public:
    Connector(const sf::Vector2f &a, const sf::Vector2f &b, const sf::Vector2f &tileSize, const sf::Color &color) : arrow{sf::TrianglesStrip, 7} {
        auto c = b - a;
        auto width = std::min(tileSize.x, tileSize.y)/4;
        auto len = std::sqrt(c.x * c.x + c.y * c.y);
        arrow[0].position = sf::Vector2f(2*width, 0);
        arrow[1].position = sf::Vector2f(1*width, 0);
        arrow[2].position = sf::Vector2f(2*width, len - 2*width);
        arrow[3].position = sf::Vector2f(1*width, len - 2*width);
        arrow[4].position = sf::Vector2f(1.5*width, len);  // arrow point
        arrow[5].position = sf::Vector2f(0*width, len - 2*width);
        arrow[6].position = sf::Vector2f(3*width, len - 2*width);
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
            arrow[i].color = color;
        }
        setOrigin(sf::Vector2f(1.5*width, 0));
        setPosition(a);
        rotate(atan2f(c.y, c.x)*180/M_PIl - 90);
    }
private:
    virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const
    {
        states.transform *= getTransform();
        states.texture = NULL;
        target.draw(arrow, states);
    }
    sf::VertexArray arrow;
};

/*
 * About numbering: The numbering is a bit unusual for computer programs.
 * For example a 4 (width) x 3 (height) grid would be numbered like this:
 *
 *    9  10  11  12
 *    8   7   6   5
 *    1   2   3   4
 *
 * Overlaying row and column numbering onto this we have
 *
 *        0   1   2   3  <-- column
 *     +---------------
 *   0 |  9  10  11  12
 *   1 |  8   7   6   5
 *   2 |  1   2   3   4
 *   ^
 *   |
 *  row
 *
 * So to find the row coordinate from the square number, we can use this:
 *  
 *    unsigned row = height - 1 - (square - 1) / width;
 *
 * Getting the column is a bit trickier since the direction of numbering alternates
 * for each row, but if we get the row first, it can be done like this:
 *
 *    unsigned col = (height - row) & 1 ? (square - 1) % width : width - 1 - (square - 1) % width;
 *
 */
class Grid : public sf::Drawable, public sf::Transformable {
public:
    bool load(unsigned width, unsigned height, unsigned across, unsigned down, const std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> &transits) {
        m_down = down;
        m_across = across;
        m_tileSize = sf::Vector2f(width/m_across, height/m_down);
        m_vertices.setPrimitiveType(sf::Lines);
        m_vertices.resize((m_across + m_down + 2) * 2);
        // make vertical lines
        for (unsigned i = 0; i <= m_across; ++i) {
            sf::Vertex* line = &m_vertices[i * 2];
            line[0].position = sf::Vector2f(i * m_tileSize.x, 0);
            line[1].position = sf::Vector2f(i * m_tileSize.x, m_down * m_tileSize.y);
            line[0].color = sf::Color::Black;
            line[1].color = sf::Color::Black;
        }
        // make horizontal lines
        for (unsigned i = 0; i <= m_down; ++i) {
            sf::Vertex* line = &m_vertices[(i + m_across + 1) * 2];
            line[0].position = sf::Vector2f(0, i * m_tileSize.y);
            line[1].position = sf::Vector2f(m_across * m_tileSize.x, i * m_tileSize.y);
            line[0].color = sf::Color::Black;
            line[1].color = sf::Color::Black;
        }
        // load a font
        m_font.loadFromFile("times.ttf");
        // label each square
        for (unsigned i = 1; i < 1 + m_across * m_down; ++i) {
            unsigned row = m_down - 1 - (i - 1) / m_across;
            unsigned col = (m_down - row) & 1 ? (i - 1) % m_across : m_across - 1 - (i - 1) % m_across;
            // Create a text
            sf::Text t = sf::Text(std::to_string(i), m_font);
            t.setCharacterSize(20);
            sf::FloatRect box = t.getLocalBounds();
            t.setPosition(col * m_tileSize.x + (m_tileSize.x - box.width)/2, row * m_tileSize.y);
            t.setColor(sf::Color::Blue);
            m_text.emplace_back(t);
        }
        for (unsigned i=0; i < transits.size(); ++i) {
            m_line.push_back(makeLine(transits[i].first, transits[i].second));
        }
        return true;
    }
private:
    sf::Vector2i indexOf(unsigned square) const {
        unsigned row = m_down - 1 - (square - 1) / m_across;
        unsigned col = (m_down - row) & 1 ? (square - 1) % m_across : m_across - 1 - (square - 1) % m_across;
        return sf::Vector2i(col, row);
    }
    sf::Vector2f centerOf(unsigned square) const {
        auto box = indexOf(square);
        return sf::Vector2f(m_tileSize.x * (0.5 + box.x), m_tileSize.y * (0.5 + box.y));
    }
    Connector makeLine(unsigned start, unsigned finish) const {
        const sf::Color &color = finish > start ? sf::Color::Green : sf::Color::Red;
        Connector rect(centerOf(start), centerOf(finish), m_tileSize, color);
        return rect;
    }

    virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const
    {
        states.transform *= getTransform();
        target.draw(m_vertices, states);
        for (const auto &t : m_text) {
            target.draw(t, states);
        }
        for (const auto &va : m_line) {
            target.draw(va, states);
        }
    }
    unsigned m_down;
    unsigned m_across;
    sf::Vector2f m_tileSize;
    sf::VertexArray m_vertices;
    sf::Font m_font;
    std::vector<sf::Text> m_text;
    std::vector<Connector> m_line;
};


int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(600, 600), "Chutes and Ladders");
    sf::Event event;
    sf::View view;
    view.reset(sf::FloatRect(-20, -20, 600, 600));
    window.setView(view);

    Grid grid;
    if (!grid.load(400, 400, 10, 10, createLinks()))
        return -1;

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        // handle events
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear(sf::Color::White);
        window.draw(grid);
        window.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I like the image rather than just coordinate pairs!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. I'm a little bothered by the piecemeal conversion from rectangular to polar coordinates. I think I'd rather wrap them up into a little neater package:

   ```
   std::pair<float, float> r2p(float cx, float cy) {
       auto len = std::sqrt(cx * cx + cy * cy);
       auto angle = atan2(cy, cx)*180/M_PIl - 90;
       return {len, angle};
   }
   ```

   It's open to some argument that it would be better still to define a `polar_coordinate` class (and probably a rectangular coordinate class as well), with each providing a constructor from the other (or a conversion operator to the other) so the compiler can help a little bit in enforcing type safety.
2. You've used copy initialization syntax a few places for no particularly good reason I can see. For example:

   ```
   sf::Text t = sf::Text(std::to_string(i), m_font);
   ```

   I'd generally prefer something like:

   ```
   sf::Text t {std::to_string(i), m_font};
   ```

   Depending on the overloaded ctors `sf::Text` provides, this can change the meaning though. If you run into that, I'd use `auto` instead:

   ```
   auto t = sf::Text(std::to_string(i), m_font);
   ```
3. You've defined `Grid::indexOf`, and `Grid::centerOf`, but in `Grid::load`, you duplicate the logic of `indexOf` exactly, and could probably use `centerOf` to simplify the logic for setting the text location as well (although this isn't quite as precise of duplication).